# How to turn off logging into the console in Mockserver Ruby client

Tags: ruby, mockserver

I am creating an expectation using the Ruby client for [mockserver](http://www.mock-server.com/) and getting a bunch of logging messages in the console(terminal).  I was wondering how to turn that off, but not print it out to a file.

I have tried this but it only prints it out to a file

```
client = MockServerClient.new(Config.mockserver.host, Config.mockserver.port)
client.logger = LoggingFactory::DEFAULT_FACTORY.log('yo', output: 'tmp.log', truncate: true)
```

Comment: `1>&2 > /dev/null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chose whichever of these.

- Logging in console: `client.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`
- Logging into file: `client.logger = Logger.new('log/foo.log', 'daily')`
- Logging nothing: `client.logger = Logger.new(nil)`